# Is it possible to use a dart function as a callback function in C?

Tags: dart, ffi

Is it possible, using **ffi**, to pass a pointer to the of **dart** function into a **C** module (i.e., to the * .so library) and access this dart function directly from the * .so library and use it by means call back?

Comment: Have you looked at: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-ffi/Pointer/fromFunction.html ?

Comment: Maybe. Can I find an example of using this function somewhere?

Answer (score 6):

Thank you very much for the information. This is what I need.

*dart:*

```
int myPlus(int a, int b) {
  print("dart.myPlus.a=$a,b=$b. $a+$b => ${a + b}");
  return a + b;
}

main() {
  ...   
  ffi.Pointer<ffi.NativeFunction<NativeIntptrBinOp>>
    pointer = ffi.Pointer.fromFunction(myPlus, 0);
  print(pointer);

  ffi.Pointer<ffi.NativeFunction<NativeApplyTo42And74Type>>
    p17 = dylib.lookup("ApplyTo42And74");
  ApplyTo42And74Type applyTo42And74 = p17.asFunction();
  int result = applyTo42And74(pointer);
  print("result => $result");
}
```

*c:*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef intptr_t (*IntptrBinOp)(intptr_t a, intptr_t b);

intptr_t ApplyTo42And74(IntptrBinOp binop) {
  printf("ApplyTo42And74()\n");
  intptr_t retval = binop(42, 74);
  printf("returning %lu\n", retval);
  return retval;
}
```

*result:*

```
Pointer<NativeFunction<(IntPtr, IntPtr) => IntPtr>>: address=0x7fb4acd98000
ApplyTo42And74()
dart.myPlus.a=42,b=74. 42+74 => 116
returning 116
result => 116
```

Comment: The issue in github provides similiar example code: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/35761

Comment: But I got the error: "The type 'Function' given to 'fromFunction' must be a valid 'dart:ffi' native function type.
Try changing the type to only use members for 'dart:ffi'."

Answer (score 3):

This is now possible using the [NativeCallable](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.1.0/dart-ffi/NativeCallable-class.html) class.

Here is an [example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ffi/NativeCallable/NativeCallable.listener.html)